# position: "absolute" with Button is not working on IOS | React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a hamburger button that triggers a side menu in a mobile app. The button doesn't respond when position is set to absolute. I have seen similar issue which suggest wrapping the button with `<View> </View>` and setting its position to absolute, however this didn't work in my case. The button doesn't respond when being clicked on IOS. Android works perfectly fine

Code Snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import Hamburger from "@psyycker/rn-animated-hamburger";

function HamburgerIcon({ navigation }) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("drawerClose", (e) => {
      setStatus(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  async function callBack() {
    setStatus(true);
    navigation.toggleDrawer();
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 40, marginLeft: 20 }}>
          <Hamburger
            active={status}
            type="spinArrow"
            color="blue"
            onPress={() => callBack()}
          ></Hamburger>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by wrapping around `SafeAreaView` and setting `zIndex` to a high number.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ position: "absolute", margin: 40, marginLeft: 20, zIndex:99999 }}>
    <Hamburger active={status}
           type="spinArrow"
           color="blue"
           onPress={() => callBack()}
          >
    </Hamburger>
</SafeAreaView>
```